# Webdriver.IO Dealing with Single Sign On cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, cookies, single-sign-on, webdriver-io

I'm creating some node.js webdriverio tests.  When I connect to any of my sites, there's a check for the presence of a ssosession cookie (among others) to confirm user has access to the page.  If it's not there, the browser immediately redirects to our login page.  I need to capture the resulting cookies from a successful login and use them to load the pages I want to test.

In curl, I do that like this:

```
curl -H"Content-type: application/json" --user-agent "MyTestAgent" --cookie-jar cookiefile -o - --data-ascii "{\"user_id\": \"username\", \"user_secret\": \"password\"}" -X POST https://loginpage.net
```

Then:

```
curl -H"Content-type: application/json" --user-agent "MyTestAgent" --cookie cookiefile - --cookie-jar cookiefile -o - https://testpage.net
```

Currently in my code, when I hit the url of the page I intend to test it immediately redirects to the login page, I enter the login credentials and it logs in successfully.  I then dump the cookies out to console and they're not updated.  The ssosession stuff isn't there (yet?).  If I console.log the ssosession alone, it's null.  If I console.log all the cookies, they're the same as if I just grabbed the cookies from the login page without signing in.  None of the SSO stuff is present.

```
describe('testpage.net page', function () {
    it('should login', function () {
        browser.url('https://testpage.net');
        //this immediately redirects to https://loginpage.net
        browser.setValue('#userid','noone@nowhere.net');
        browser.setValue('#passwd','S3cr3tP4ssw0rd');
        browser.submitForm('#login');
        console.log(browser.getCookie('ssosession'));
        //returns null
        console.log(browser.getCookie());
        //returns cookies that existed prior to login success
    });
});
```

I need a means to grab the post login success cookies, store them locally equivalent to curls cookiejar and use them in subsequent tests.  I've been beating my head up against a wall trying to figure out how this is done.  This is an internal site that has very dated authentication method, but I need to write test automation for it's gui.  Once over this particular hurdle, it should be easy to do that.  Suggestions greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem and found a workaround solution.

let's say we have two domains: `sso.example.com` and `application.example.com`

After successful login, I open a new popup window with a url of the SSO, and grab the cookies from this popup, and store them to a file.
when the test script starts I am just injecting the cookies and everything works perfect :-)

```
  // login just ended, you are at "application.example.com/sessioned-url"
  // ...
  // post login code, save cookies to file
  await saveCookies(browser);
  //open popup with sso.example.com (any url of this subdomain is OK even favicon or 404 becasue the cookies will be available)
  await browser.newWindow("https://sso.example.com", {
    windowName: "WebdriverIO window",
    windowFeature: "width=1,height=1,resizable,scrollbars=yes,status=1",
  });
  const handles = await browser.getWindowHandles();
  //move to the new window the SSO url
  await browser.switchToWindow(handles[1]);
  // save the SSO cookies (make sure to add the cookies to a file, NOT override it)
  await saveCookies(browser);

  //close popup and go back to "application.example.com/sessioned-url" window...
  await browser.closeWindow();
  await browser.switchToWindow(handles[0]);
```

when starting a new session:

```
  // inject cookies of both domains
  await injectCookies(browser);

  // main window, will goto url without forcing login
  await browser.url("application.example.com/sessioned-url");
```

hope it will help anyone in the long future :-)

Comment: Great solution.  Thanks for posting it!